# Converse of commutative projections.

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces, projection

Let $X$ be a norm space on $F(F=R\ or\ C)$, if $P$ and $Q$ are two projections of $X$, and $P,Q$ are commutative, i.e., $PQ=QP$, then we know $PQ$ is the projection onto $im P\bigcap im Q$.
I wonder whether the converse is true. That is, if $im PQ=im QP$, then do we have $PQ=QP$? It seems that this could be right, but i cannot deduce it simply from the properties of projections. 
I can get that $im P\bigcap im Q=im PQ=imQP$ and $QP=PQP,PQ=QPQ$, but what then?
If it is not true, could anyone please give a counter example?

Comment: If $QP=PQP$, $PQ=QPQ$, then $(QP)^2=Q(PQP)=Q(QP)=Q^2P=QP$ so $QP$ is a projection, and similarly $PQ$ is a projection, which should finish your proof.

Comment: I know they are projections. Here i want to show $PQ=QP$.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. You're assuming that $P,Q$ are projections such that $PQ,QP$ are projections, and that $QP$ and $PQ$ have the same image, and you want to know whether $PQ=QP$?

Comment: Yes that's what i mean. Thank you. Is my question to naive?

Comment: No, I don't think so. I just wasn't entirely sure of what you meant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, the statement is false. Let $p,q$ be projections in $\mathbb{R}^2$ with kernels $\mathbb{R}(1,1)$ and $\mathbb{R}(0,1)$ onto $\mathbb{R}(1,0)$. Then $p,q,pq,qp$ have the same image $\mathbb{R}(1,0)$. However $pq(1,1)=p(1,0)=(1,0)$ while $qp(1,1)=q(0,0)=(0,0)$ so $p,q$ do not commute.

Answer (score 3):

If two **orthgonal** projections have the same image, then they are equal: Let $P$ and $Q$ be same projections such that $\text{im } P=\text{im }Q$. Then $\text{im } P\subseteq\text{im }Q$ implies $QP=P$ and $\text{im } P\supseteq \text{im }Q$ implies $PQ=Q$. Taking adjoints in the latter $QP=Q$. Hence $P=QP=Q$.

Comment: Sorry i don't get why $QP=Q$. What if when $P$ is the orthogonal projection onto the x-y plane of  $R^3$, and $Q$ is another projection,but not orthogonal, onto the x-y plane.  Intuitively it does not hold $QP=Q$.

Comment: Since $PQ=Q$, so $(PQ)^*=Q^*=Q$. Hence $Q^*P^*=Q$. Therefore $QP=Q$.

Comment: Sorry I may not make myself clear enough. Here the projections are merely operators satisfying $P^2=P$.

Comment: Oh. Your tag was functional analysis. Usually the projections are defined as $P=P^2=P^*$.

Comment: @SahibaArora: that's not "functional analysis", but "Hilbert spaces", which is not a tag in this question.